# Overflow Menu PopUp

Tags: android, popup, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-design-library, overflow-menu

I have recently replaced the appcompat in my app with the design library ('com.android.support:design:24.2.0'). The overflow menu popup is now appearing to the centre of the screen instead of the right on the tablet I'm testing on (Samsung Tab with android 4.0.4). Its fine on other newer devices . Has anyone else experienced this? If so do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been raised as a bug with the android os.